# Bind Gridview with items asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

Hi I want to bind my gridview from a datatable which I create myself.

It's works but my columns are duplicated, I don't understand exactly why.

Here is my gridview :

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GvCalculSelect" CssClass="gridView" HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="CalculName" HeaderText="CalculName" />
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ResultValue">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CbResultValue" runat="server" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ResultValue").ToString()) %>'/>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

And here it's a part of my cs code :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

 protected void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("CalculName", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ResultValue", typeof(Boolean)));
    dt.Rows.Add("Test", true);
    GvCalculSelect.DataSource = dt;
    GvCalculSelect.DataBind();
}
```

The result is :
[image]

How to fix it ? I think when I bind my gridview is taking on board my two "dt.columns.add". I just want to keep my calculName field and my resultValue checkbox

Thanks for your help

Comment: make sure your auto generate columns is set to false.
also on the Bind() method add this as your first line 
`GvCalculSelect.DataSource = null;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are creating your own table and binding it to the GridView AS WELL AS defining 2 columns explicitly in the Gridview and binding datafields to them.

Do 1 or the other, but not both. So, to be clear if you want to control the look and feel of your columns you should set the `autogeneratecolumns` property to false. Keep your front end bound columns, but you can then remove them from the datatable and simply reference the relevant fields that are present in the datatable.

Alternatively, set `autogeneratecolumns` to true, but then construct the columns in your datatable in your code behind and then just bind it as is.

Comment: Yes that's I am thinking but I have no idea to insert properly the data directly into my gridview without pass by a datatable which I create myself

Comment: @Ironboy07 - sounds like you want some control over what the columns looks like etc. So, you don't need to create new columns in your datatable. Set autogeneratecolumns to false and just fill the datatable, bind it and then use the boundfield and templatefield to reference the correct data.

Comment: Yes thanks it works. I just set the autogeneratecolumns to false like you said. I forgot this parameters... Thanks for your quick answer !

Comment: @Ironboy07 - np. Please mark this as the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `GridView.AutoGenerateColumns Property`

You need to set its value false.

For your refrence according to MSDN

> If you set this property to true and set the ItemType property to a
>   model type, DynamicField controls are generated.
>
> If you do not set the ItemType property, BoundField controls are
>   generated. If you do not want DynamicField controls, you have the following options:

1. Set the ColumnsGenerator property to null in the Page_Load event
   handler. In that case, BoundField controls are generated.
2. Write custom code to automatically generate fields by creating and
   assigning your own ColumnsGenerator class and assigning an
       instance of it to the control.
3. Set AutoGenerateColumns to false. In that case, no fields are
   generated, and you must manually specify fields using controls such
       as BoundField or ImageField.
4. Do not set the ItemType property. In that case, BoundField controls
   are generated.